# Add variable number of sources to MediatorLiveData

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have to return a list of lists with LiveData.
The background is, that I load some data out of my Room database.
The database call depends on a counter. So I tried the following approach:

```
MediatorLiveData<List<List<Foo>> forView = new MediatorLiveData<>();
forView.addSource(counter, (trigger) -> {
   List<List<Foo>> output = new LinkedList<>();

   for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
      output.add(new ArrayList<>());
      forView.addSource(repository.getDataForCounter(i), (data) -> {
         //With some workaround I thought I've access to the position
         output.remove("i");
         output.add("i", data);
      });
   }

   return output;
});
```

I think the workaround for the index didn't work, because the variables in lambdas have to be implicit final.
Is there any other approach to "merge" a variable number of lists got out of a database in one list of such lists?

Comment: If you are willing to use RxJava, have `getDataForCounter()` return `Single<List<Foo>>`, then use `Single.zip()` to combine their results into a `List<List<Foo>>`.

Comment: I'd like to give it a try, but the deadline of the project's near and therefore I sadly can't change the dependencies...

Comment: Add a method on your repository that returns all data for all counters, then use `Transformations.map()` to split it into lists by counter.

Comment: Yeah, thought about that too. But my professor in data management said everytime: If you could use SQL to solve a task, then use it, because the queries will be more optimized.
But I think, I can ignore this at this point. Thanks

Comment: I don't actually know enough of the code to tell you what you should be doing.